# Is there a way to use .indexon on unknown keys?

Tags: c#, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

```
    {
     
      "worldboss" : {
        "bosses" : {
          "boss0" : {
            "patrick" : 9008
          },
          "boss5" : {
            "swqas" : 1018.81
          }
        }
      }
```

where 1 and 5 are the boss levels (up to infinity)
whenever a boss dies it creates a node with the new level
Now how can I add .indexon to the newly created node(I use queries to get player rank and give out rewards) to help with sorting?

```
   reference.Child("worldboss").Child("bosses").Child("boss" + wblvl.ToString()).OrderByValue().LimitToLast(50).ValueChanged += HandleValueChanged;

 void HandleValueChanged(object sender, ValueChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.DatabaseError != null)
        {
            Debug.Log(args.DatabaseError.Message);
            return;
        }
        looperr = 49;
      DataSnapshot snapo = args.Snapshot;

        foreach (var player in snapo.Children)
        {
            datas[looperr] = player.Key;
            vlaues[looperr] = int.Parse(player.GetValue(true).ToString());
            showtopdmg[looperr].text = vlaues[looperr].ToString();
            showtopname[looperr].text = datas[looperr].ToString();
            looperr = looperr - 1;
        }
```

code used to call query sorting

Comment: Can you: 1) replace the pseudo datastructure with the actual JSON (as text, no screenshots please). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data). 2) show in minimal code what query you are trying to run on this JSON? I'm specifically interested in seeing that node you run the query on, and what property you want to order/filter on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create an index for each boss, on the values of the score nodes under them, you'd use:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "worldboss": {
      "bosses": {
        "$bossid": {
          ".indexOn": ".value"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The `$` wildcard in here means that the rules under it apply to each child node under `/worldboss/bosses`